# "error_message"=>"stack level too deep", "error_class"=>"SystemStackError" #1836

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sidekiq

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/1836

I'm stuck with the following same error messages from different locations and looking forward for a guidance to come out of this issue.

All the below lies under same category "error_message"=>"stack level too deep", "error_class"=>"SystemStackError"
But throwing from different places as listed from 1 to 5

1) logging.rb:15

```
2014-07-10T06:11:36.782Z 19437 TID-ourqdth1s TwitterRealtimeWorker JID-461c4da5b70ce6d1811777d0 INFO: fail: 2.142 sec
2014-07-10T06:11:36.786Z 19437 TID-ourqdth1s WARN: {"retry"=>1, "queue"=>"default", "throttle"=>{"threshold"=>40, "period"=>120, "key"=>{}}, "failures"=>true, "class"=>"TwitterRealtimeWorker", "args"=>[103], "jid"=>"461c4da5b70ce6d1811777d0", "enqueued_at"=>1404972666.989332, "error_message"=>"stack level too deep", "error_class"=>"SystemStackError", "failed_at"=>1404972696.778065, "retry_count"=>0, "processor"=>"Shan.local:19437"}
2014-07-10T06:11:36.787Z 19437 TID-ourqdth1s WARN: stack level too deep
2014-07-10T06:11:36.787Z 19437 TID-ourqdth1s WARN: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@relatednoise/gems/sidekiq-3.2.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:15
```

2) processor.rb:106

```
2014-07-10T06:12:14.078Z 19437 TID-ourqx6gk8 TwitterRealtimeWorker JID-461c4da5b70ce6d1811777d0 INFO: Adding dead TwitterRealtimeWorker job 461c4da5b70ce6d1811777d0
2014-07-10T06:12:14.080Z 19437 TID-ourqx6gk8 TwitterRealtimeWorker JID-461c4da5b70ce6d1811777d0 INFO: fail: 0.285 sec
2014-07-10T06:12:14.081Z 19437 TID-ourqx6gk8 WARN: {"retry"=>1, "queue"=>"default", "throttle"=>{"threshold"=>40, "period"=>120, "key"=>{}}, "failures"=>true, "class"=>"TwitterRealtimeWorker", "args"=>[103], "jid"=>"461c4da5b70ce6d1811777d0", "enqueued_at"=>1404972666.989332, "error_message"=>"stack level too deep", "error_class"=>"SystemStackError", "failed_at"=>1404972734.0797381, "retry_count"=>1, "retried_at"=>1404972734.0788622, "processor"=>"Shan.local:19437"}
2014-07-10T06:12:14.081Z 19437 TID-ourqx6gk8 WARN: stack level too deep
2014-07-10T06:12:14.081Z 19437 TID-ourqx6gk8 WARN: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@relatednoise/gems/sidekiq-3.2.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:106
```

3) task_fiber.rb:23

```
2014-07-10T06:12:03.131Z 19437 TID-ourqx6gk8 TwitterRealtimeWorker JID-f066590cbd79930efab64db2 INFO: Adding dead TwitterRealtimeWorker job f066590cbd79930efab64db2
2014-07-10T06:12:03.133Z 19437 TID-ourqx6gk8 TwitterRealtimeWorker JID-f066590cbd79930efab64db2 INFO: fail: 0.903 sec
2014-07-10T06:12:03.136Z 19437 TID-ourqx6gk8 WARN: {"retry"=>1, "queue"=>"default", "throttle"=>{"threshold"=>40, "period"=>120, "key"=>{}}, "failures"=>true, "class"=>"TwitterRealtimeWorker", "args"=>[102], "jid"=>"f066590cbd79930efab64db2", "enqueued_at"=>1404972665.862527, "error_message"=>"stack level too deep", "error_class"=>"SystemStackError", "failed_at"=>1404972723.1333828, "retry_count"=>1, "retried_at"=>1404972723.1315699, "processor"=>"Shan.local:19437"}
2014-07-10T06:12:03.137Z 19437 TID-ourqx6gk8 WARN: stack level too deep
2014-07-10T06:12:03.137Z 19437 TID-ourqx6gk8 WARN: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@relatednoise/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:23
2014-07-10T06:12:13.795Z 19437 TID-ourqx6gk8 TwitterRealtimeWorker JID-461c4da5b70ce6d1811777d0 INFO: start
```

4) retry_jobs.rb:109

```
2014-07-10T06:12:02.796Z 19437 TID-ourqdth1s TwitterRealtimeWorker JID-5c2dab540501a7e3aa052990 INFO: Adding dead TwitterRealtimeWorker job 5c2dab540501a7e3aa052990
2014-07-10T06:12:02.806Z 19437 TID-ourqdth1s TwitterRealtimeWorker JID-5c2dab540501a7e3aa052990 INFO: fail: 0.613 sec
2014-07-10T06:12:02.829Z 19437 TID-ourqdth1s WARN: {"retry"=>1, "queue"=>"default", "throttle"=>{"threshold"=>40, "period"=>120, "key"=>{}}, "failures"=>true, "class"=>"TwitterRealtimeWorker", "args"=>[99], "jid"=>"5c2dab540501a7e3aa052990", "enqueued_at"=>1404972664.478233, "error_message"=>"stack level too deep", "error_class"=>"SystemStackError", "failed_at"=>1404972722.805805, "retry_count"=>1, "retried_at"=>1404972722.796501, "processor"=>"Shan.local:19437"}
2014-07-10T06:12:02.830Z 19437 TID-ourqdth1s WARN: stack level too deep
2014-07-10T06:12:02.833Z 19437 TID-ourqdth1s WARN: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@relatednoise/gems/sidekiq-3.2.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:109
```

5) transactions.rb:274

```
2014-07-10T06:12:02.794Z 19437 TID-ourqdn5m0 TwitterRealtimeWorker JID-2381d4bcaf49ffb6f4c3a676 INFO: Adding dead TwitterRealtimeWorker job 2381d4bcaf49ffb6f4c3a676
2014-07-10T06:12:02.806Z 19437 TID-ourqdn5m0 TwitterRealtimeWorker JID-2381d4bcaf49ffb6f4c3a676 INFO: fail: 0.615 sec
2014-07-10T06:12:02.819Z 19437 TID-ourqdn5m0 WARN: {"retry"=>1, "queue"=>"default", "throttle"=>{"threshold"=>40, "period"=>120, "key"=>{}}, "failures"=>true, "class"=>"TwitterRealtimeWorker", "args"=>[97], "jid"=>"2381d4bcaf49ffb6f4c3a676", "enqueued_at"=>1404972662.09458, "error_message"=>"stack level too deep", "error_class"=>"SystemStackError", "failed_at"=>1404972722.804928, "retry_count"=>1, "retried_at"=>1404972722.794392, "processor"=>"Shan.local:19437"}
2014-07-10T06:12:02.819Z 19437 TID-ourqdn5m0 WARN: stack level too deep
2014-07-10T06:12:02.821Z 19437 TID-ourqdn5m0 WARN: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@relatednoise/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:274
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what is triggering this behavior

Comment: You should log more lines from the stack-trace - it is hard to see the recursive loop if you display only one line ("stack level too deep" is thrown _somewhere_ in an infinite recursion loop...)

Comment: Also, before troubling mperham, I think you should at _your_ code for the problem. Most chances are that it is in your code. Opening an issue with close to no data at all is not very helpful or considerate...

Answer (score 0):

Sidekiq 3 does not support Ruby 1.9.